# MLab database created with microsoft azure resulting to Connection error: MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: mongodb, azure, mlab

I have two `mongo` databases created in mLab. The first one is created directly from my personal account on mLab.

`mongodb://nottheactualuser:123456@ds011168.mlab.com:11168/db1`

The other was created from **Microsoft Azure Portal > Marketplace**.

`mongodb://nottheactualuser:123456@ds064278.mlab.com:64278/db1`

The first one is connecting successfully while the other one created from **Azure** is producing this error.

`Connection error: MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Has anyone encountered this yet? How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Second host does not respond to `ping`, so it probably is not even running. That wasn't hard to test now was it.

Comment: What do you mean "does not respond to ping" ? If you're talking about the `mongodb://nottheactualuser:123456@ds064278.mlab.com:64278/db1` their not the actual credentials.

Comment: @BlakesSeven   here.

Comment: I'm taking about the actual hostname of course `ping ds064278.mlab.com` is unreachable. The first responds just fine. You cannot connect to an unreachable address.

Comment: BTW @BlakesSeven thanks for always responding to my questions. You help me a lot :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: @BlakesSeven oooh I see. Yes I tried it and yes it's not responding. That's weird. I'm sure I used the links copied from mongolab.

Comment: If you haven't already, contact mLab support for assistance: support@mlab.com

Comment: Already did @pneumee :) lll add the solution  now.

Answer (score 1):

Upon contacting the mlab support they told me this.

I cannot use the URL directly from mLab -

> -Because the ICMP protocol is not permitted through the Azure load balancer, you will notice that you are unable to ping an Azure VM from the internet. You can read more about that here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity/

my mistake was I assumed that it would be fine to use the link directly from mLab. So I search further more and I came across with this [post](http://blog.mlab.com/2013/02/node-js-and-mongolab-on-windows-azure/).

**TL;DR**

- Login you youre azure classic portal
- Navigate to **Market Place** and select your mLab database and click connection info.
  [image]
- A window will appear containing the **MONGOLAB_URI** you needed.
- Copy and use that.
- And lastly don't be like me.

I hope this helps.